# nmake fails when attempting to compile argon2_elixir

Tags: elixir, dependency-management, nmake, elixir-mix

I'm trying to add `argon2_elixir` to my phoenix project, but I get this error when compiling:

```
mix compile
==> argon2_elixir

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.24210.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

makefile(34) : fatal error U1000: syntax error : ')' missing in macro invocation
Stop.
could not compile dependency :argon2_elixir, "mix compile" failed. You can recompile this dependency with "mix deps.compile argon2_elixir", update it with "mix deps.update argon2_elixir" or clean it with "mix deps.clean argon2_elixir"
==> chatter
** (Mix) Could not compile with "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\nmake.exe" (exit status: 2).
One option is to install a recent version of
[Visual C++ Build Tools](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools)
either manually or using [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) -
`choco install VisualCppBuildTools`.

After installing Visual C++ Build Tools, look in the "Program Files (x86)"
directory and search for "Microsoft Visual Studio". Note down the full path
of the folder with the highest version number. Open the "run" command and
type in the following command (make sure that the path and version number
are correct):

    cmd /K "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64

This should open up a command prompt with the necessary environment variables
set, and from which you will be able to run the "mix compile", "mix deps.compile",
and "mix test" commands.
```

Before this error, it previously mentioned how `nmake.exe` was not found and to set that as the `MAKE` system variable. So I went into environmental variables and set the path to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\nmake.exe`.

If I open cmd/powershell with the following command `cmd /K "C:\..." amd64` I have to `cd` back into the phoenix project. After running `mix compile`/`mix deps.compile argon2_elixir`, it gives me the same error.

I notice that there's a [closed github issue](https://github.com/riverrun/argon2_elixir/issues/20) but it doesn't have a solution.

Here's my mix.ex file

```elixir
defmodule Chatter.MixProject do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [
      app: :chatter,
      version: "0.1.0",
      elixir: "~> 1.5",
      elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env()),
      compilers: [:phoenix, :gettext] ++ Mix.compilers(),
      start_permanent: Mix.env() == :prod,
      aliases: aliases(),
      deps: deps()
    ]
  end

  # Configuration for the OTP application.
  #
  # Type `mix help compile.app` for more information.
  def application do
    [
      mod: {Chatter.Application, []},
      extra_applications: [:logger, :runtime_tools, :phoenix, :phoenix_pubsub, :phoenix_html, :cowboy, :logger, :gettext,
      :phoenix_ecto, :postgrex, :comeonin ]
    ]
  end

  # Specifies which paths to compile per environment.
  defp elixirc_paths(:test), do: ["lib", "test/support"]
  defp elixirc_paths(_), do: ["lib"]

  # Specifies your project dependencies.
  #
  # Type `mix help deps` for examples and options.
  defp deps do
    [
      {:phoenix, "~> 1.4.1"},
      {:phoenix_pubsub, "~> 1.1"},
      {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 4.0"},
      {:ecto_sql, "~> 3.0"},
      {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
      {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.11"},
      {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.2", only: :dev},
      {:gettext, "~> 0.11"},
      {:jason, "~> 1.0"},
      {:plug_cowboy, "~> 2.0"},
      {:comeonin, "~> 5.1.1"},
      {:argon2_elixir, "~> 2.0"}
    ]
  end

  # Aliases are shortcuts or tasks specific to the current project.
  # For example, to create, migrate and run the seeds file at once:
  #
  #     $ mix ecto.setup
  #
  # See the documentation for `Mix` for more info on aliases.
  defp aliases do
    [
      "ecto.setup": ["ecto.create", "ecto.migrate", "run priv/repo/seeds.exs"],
      "ecto.reset": ["ecto.drop", "ecto.setup"],
      test: ["ecto.create --quiet", "ecto.migrate", "test"]
    ]
  end
end
```

Comment: It's specifically a argon2_elixir issue because if i remove that dependancy then I can run comeonin properly

Comment: @Adam thanks for the editing tips :)

Comment: So it finds an error on line 34 in `makefile` - but argon2_elixir also has [a Makefile.win file](https://github.com/riverrun/argon2_elixir/blob/master/Makefile.win). I guess the problem is that _something_ is choosing to run `Makefile` instead of `Makefile.win`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting an error on line 34 in `Makefile`.  It is supposed to use `Makefile.win` instead of `Makefile` on Windows, but in this case it doesn't.

It turns out that this is a "feature" of `elixir_make`.  If the make executable to be used is `nmake`, it uses the arguments `/F Makefile.win`, otherwise it doesn't specify which makefile to use, and `nmake` presumably falls back to using `Makefile`.  That happens [here](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir_make/blob/82c53a2cf0c7a5a063e045c31015b9206f3a3217/lib/mix/tasks/compile.make.ex#L228-L231).

But since you're setting the `MAKE` environment variable to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\nmake.exe`, this no longer compares equal to `nmake`, and so `Makefile` is used instead of `Makefile.win` - and you get an error.

I would suggest two things:

- Instead of setting the `MAKE` environment variable, change `PATH` to include the directory where `nmake.exe` is.
- [Report a bug in `elixir_make`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir_make/issues).  It should probably check if the executable specified by `MAKE` has the filename `nmake` or `nmake.exe` regardless of directory, instead of simply comparing against the string `"nmake"`.

Comment: Just to point out, anyone who comes across the `Makefile.win` the reason is, you either have a `makefile` in the directory, and if so simply create another file called `Makefile.win` do not have any actual `env` If statements, etc in it or it will error.

It will automatically finish compiling... LoL